# Is it possible to store else-if statements in a XML file and call it from activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on a project in which I have thousands of HTML files placed in assets folder and I want to open them in webview but the problem is that I can't have such a huge sized code in my java file. I was wondering if there is any way to store the else-if statements in an XML file (statements.xml) and refer the XML file in my class file.

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
WebView web;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
if(pos==0){    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/games.html");
else if(pos==1){    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/softwares.html");}   
else if(pos==2){    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/music.html");}       
else if(pos==3){    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/themes.html");}        
else if(pos==4){    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/wallpapers.html");}

 // similarly for 4 and 5 and so on.
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;

}
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
        String description, String failingUrl) {
}
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

 }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create the URL with the `pos` value directly ? You'll avoid your if/else statements.

It would be something like that

```
int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
String url = "file:///android_asset/"+pos+".html"
web.loadUrl(url);
```

Ok it seems like you have different file names. So what you can do is store those in a Map.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0,"games");
map.put(1,"softwares");
map.put(2, "music");
/*****
 And so on
*****/
int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
String url = "file:///android_asset/"+map.get(pos)+".html"
web.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Because i have problem with it, please dont ask questions , instead, answer my question if you can.

Comment: check my code now , i cannot rename all the files from 1-999 (CUS I DONT WANT TO !!)

Comment: @Anonymous `Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();` for an `HashMap` for example.

Comment: i just want to store the statements in some other place which allows huge codes. your code sounds like i have to all my html file names in the map.put(0,"games");thing  :,(  i already told in question that i cannot have such large amounts of code in a class file because of its 63356 byte limit cus i have thousands of html files        :,( now i dont know how do i make you understand all this...

Comment: Since you don't want to rename the files and you don't want to create a hashmap in the code (as far as i see you have problem with long code in java files) you can create a string-array resource with the urls and in the code just request the item from the string-array based on the pos

Answer (score 1):

Create a string array:
create a resource file in the res/values folder lets say html_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="html_map">
        <item
            >file:///android_asset/softwares.html</item>
        <item>file:///android_asset/softwares2.html </item>

    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and so on.

In the code you can use

```
String[] pages = getStringArray(R.array.html_map);
```

And then use web.loadUrl(pages[pos]);

Comment: where do i add String[] pages = getStringArray(R.array.html_map); in my code? what lines do i have to remove from my code? :,(

Comment: I have to work too, not just staying here. So you build up your string-array and you can use the String[] pages part right after web.getSettings() lines. You have to remove the lot of the if else part and instead of that use the web.loadUrl(pages[pos]); method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+pos+".html");
```

Answer (score 0):

maintain `xml file` inside your `assets` folder which can be **parsed** and read anytime.

**i.e.:**

**`mapping.xml`**

```
<array>
<dict>
    <Index>1</Index>
    <PageName>games.html</PageName>
</dict>
<dict>
    <Index>2</Index>
    <PageName>softwares.html</PageName>
</dict>
<dict>
    <Index>3</Index>
    <PageName>music.html</PageName>
</dict>
</array>
```

Now, whenever you want to load the page, you can identify it accordingly.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Answer (score -1):

```
String url = "file:///android_asset/"+pos+".html";
web.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: dear @GopalRao I have answered then the question was changed or edited !!